# Angular HttpClient+firebase- how to maintain logged state after page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm using firebase as a backen with angular , I use http requests to communicate with firebase ,
I want to persist the logged in status after the refresh of the page

```js
doGoogleLogin() {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      provider.addScope('profile');
      provider.addScope('email');
      this.afAuth.auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(res => {
          resolve(res);
          firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then((tok) => {
            this.token = tok;
          });
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I suggest you read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

Comment: i solved this using localStorage